# docker container of api not accessible from another container of docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose with flask app and some tests written in python to test the api. The api is working fine but the containers with the tests return this error :
equests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='my_api', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /Authorization (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f02ff5abf10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')).

here is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.9"

networks:
  app_subnet:
    external: true
    

services:
       api:
         image: my_api
         container_name: my_api
         networks:
              app_subnet :
                    ipv4_address: 172.16.0.10
         ports:
              - "5000:5000"
              #- target: 5000
               # published: 5000
               # protocol: tcp
               # mode: host
       
       authentication:
          image: authentication
          depends_on:
              - api
          container_name: authentication_test
          networks:
                    - app_subnet 
                        
          volumes:
              - /home/oussama/Downloads/projet2/:/home/


volumes:
  shared_volume:
       name: shared_volume
       driver: local
       driver_opts:
              type: 'none'
              o: 'bind'
              device: '/home/oussama/Downloads/projet2'
```

one of the tests that i am running :

```
import os
import requests

# définition de l'adresse de l'API
api_address = 'my_api'
# port de l'API
api_port = 5000


r = requests.get(
    url='http://{address}:{port}/Authorization'.format(address=api_address, port=api_port),
    headers= {
        'Authorization': 'alice=wonderland'
        }
)

output = '''
============================
    Authentication test
============================

request done at "/Authorization"
| username="alice"
| password="wonderland"

expected result = 200
actual restult = {status_code}

==>  {test_status}

'''


# statut de la requête
status_code = r.status_code

# affichage des résultats
if status_code == 200:
    test_status = 'SUCCESS'
else:
    test_status = 'FAILURE'
print(output.format(status_code=status_code, test_status=test_status))
```

the api is working after the docker-compose and i get the results that i want with curl command on the port 5000. I checked and no other process is using this port. I tried to change the api_adress in the test code to the ipv4_address that i fixed in the yml file or used the api container_name directly and both times i have the same error : Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'

Any ideas please ?

Comment: I think your `api` service host should be `api` and not `my_api` which is the container name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately i still get the same error when i put the service's name in the url. (but i think you put the container's name not the service but either way i get the same error)

Comment: Can you show the curl command you used that worked?

Comment: curl localhost:5000/Authorization -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: bob=builder' -X GET  and curl 172.16.0.10:5000/Authorization -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: bob=builder' -X GET  both work and return the result i expected from the api

Comment: same goes for the username and password alice wonderland curl 172.16.0.10:5000/Authorization -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: alice=wonderland' -X GET

Comment: Is there a reason you've set the `external: true` parameter on your network?

Comment: i just defined a network outside of my docker-compose with docker network create --gateway 172.16.0.1 --subnet 172.16.0.0/24 app_subnet so that i can fix a ipv4 adress for my api in my docker-compose. This way i can define the url with this fixed adress in my test file.

Comment: I think this outside network is not directly routable to the application. Are you binding this IP address to port 5000 inside flask as well?

Comment: ah ok i see what you mean. this adress is not known inside my flask app. for the flask app it is just running on localhost on port 5000. in the dockerfile for the api i expose the port 5000 and then in my docker-compose i assign the ipv4 adress. Maybe this is my mistake ?

Comment: Most definitely, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your `Flask` application is listening on the correct address as you've listed in the `docker-compose` file here.

`localhost` does *NOT* work, because of different network namespaces that each container has, it means a different host for different containers.

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt work. The api container doesnt work it shows the following error : Cannot assign requested address. And the test container still shows the same error...

Answer (score 0):

in my flask app i end it with the following :
if **name** == "**main**":
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)

in the dockerfile i expose the port 5000 and the if i do :
docker container run -p 5000:5000 -d my_api:latest

the api responds to my curl command using localhost